# Easy and correct way of navigation using keyboard on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the easiest and cross-browser correct way of adding the option to navigate a web page using keyboard input? Designing a really wide and long page right now and would like to offer users the option to scroll across using only the keyboard too.

There might be sections with divs wrapped in  tags on it and ideally I want the transition to be smooth from one div to the other when pressing "left" "right" "up" or "down" keys.

Thank you!

Comment: By binding to one of the javascript key events, figuring out what key was pressed, and moving stuff on your page accordingly.

Comment: I think using arrow keys for scrolling a page is a standard, function in most browsers. Just checked in FF, Chrome, and IE10 all of them seem top do it naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in a browser there is default behaviour for the arrow keys. They scroll across the page if it's longer or wider than your page.

If your page is scrollable you shouldn't really override the arrow keys, they already work.

There are cases though where you might want to bind events to specific keys. But I suggest you use <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of arrow keys.

I'll try to do this in plain JavaScript as I don't want to force you to be using any framework, but I'll provide a jQuery alternative too.

First, there are quite a few ways browsers seem to register keypresses. I'm looking at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) which is an exceptional information source on how browsers handle non-standard or even standard things. I go there quite often for figuring out "best practices".

It tells me that the best (most widely supported) event I can use is `keydown`. Also that the most reliable way to read the pressed key from the event is reading the `event.keyCode`. According to MDN, this is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/keydown), and you should use `key` (which is marked as not implemented), but at least `event.keyCode` works consistently across browsers. So you can handle keypresses like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event; // for more compatibility
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;

    console.log(keyCode + " was pressed");

    switch(keyCode) {
        case 37: // left key was pressed
            handleLeft();
            e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behaviour to trigger
            break;
        case 38: // up key was pressed
            handleUp();
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        case 39: // right key was pressed
            handleRight();
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        case 40: // down key was pressed
            handleDown();
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        default:
            // there are quite a few keycodes left :)
            break;
    }
}
```

`keyCode` is an unsigned integer, the encodinc is either [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but that's the same for normal keys. If you are not sure, then `alert()` or `console.log()` the pressed key, so you can check it's code.

If you are using jQuery the `event.which` property is normalized on the [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event, so you can use it like:

```
$('document').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 37) {
         alert('left key was pressed');
    }
});
```

---

Now on how to handle the navigation. If I understand you correctly, you want to scroll the window.

[`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scroll) is not part of a standard, but is supported everywhere. Also [`window.scollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollBy) and [`window.scrollByPages`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollByPages) helps you to scroll a relative amount.

So for example you could write the `handleLeft()` function from the code before like this:

```
function handleLeft() {
    window.scrollBy(-1 * window.innerWidth, 0);
}
```

This scrolls one page to the left.

I'm confident that you will be able to build your code form this.

Comment: Thank you, this was really detailed and explained it well!